# Does PHP session_name(name) sets the cookie name?

Tags: php, session-cookies

That is `name` in `setcookie(name,...)` is the same thing we pass to `session_name(name)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. From the [documentation](http://php.net/session_name).

> The session name references the name of the session, which is used in
>   cookies and URLs (e.g. PHPSESSID).